# Как заставить программу на python работать в фоновом режиме?

Tags: python

Есть [программа](https://github.com/canadien91/psychic-spice), которая неплохо справляется со своей задачей на относительно небольших числах, но когда числа увеличиваются, программа съедает всю память и делает моему процессору больно.

Я хочу переписать программу так, чтобы она хранила объекты в базе данных и выполняла действия над объектами в фоновом режиме. При этом я хочу ограничить потребляемые программой ресурсы, чтобы она не сильно нагружала процессор и не кушала много памяти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Отдельный процесс -- вам смотреть либо на модуль threading, либо multiprocessing.
2. Вы вовсе не обязаны все данные хранить в памяти, а если речь идёт о строковых ресурсах вы вполне можете привлечь модуль ziplib, либо записывать и считывать данные из файла порциями.
3. Если читаете из файла -- можете хранить zip-файл  в памяти -- модуль mmap вам в помощь.
4. Привлечение расширения cython поможет вам сократить потребление памяти в 5-8 раз, и ускорит ваши вычисления в 5-140 раз.
5. Убедительная просьба: дублируйте ваши комментарии на русском языке. Не используйте сложные специфические конструкции. Не грешите скрытым атрибутами (они используются по другому).

[pyPC на гитхабе](http://github.com/prospero78)

Comment: Да тут много способов)  Можно вообще на С/С++ написать и использовать OpenMP.
Спасибо за ответ, хотя проблема слегка потеряла актуальность.

Answer (score 3):

[[@Montreal](/users/11712/montreal)](/users/11712/montreal), вы можите очень просто значительно сократить использование памяти при помощи [механизма слотов](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots). По сути вам нужно добавить всего одну сточку:

```
class AHuman( object ):
    __slots__ = ( '__sex_genes', '__mag_genes', ... )
    ...
```

В вашем случае, это должно сократить потребление памяти раз в 5.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, спасибо! Программа теперь не только потребляет меньше памяти, но и работает значительно быстрее!

Answer (score 2):

[[@Montreal](/users/11712/montreal)](/users/11712/montreal), с процессором и фоном особых проблем, думаю, нет

```
nohup nice your-prog args &
```

(см. man nohup, man nice)

должно вполне подойти, если программа не интерактивная.

А вот с памятью сложнее (конечно, можно взлянуть на ulimit в bash). Что именно Вы хотите ограничить, и собственно, что должно произойти при превышении ограничений?

Comment: @avp, программа не интерактивная: создаются стартовые условия (количество человек, описанных в классе **human.py**, год, в который должна произойти мутация) и дальше идёт просто цикл, за одну итерацию которого в социуме проходит год. Ограничивать количество потребляемой памяти, видимо, придётся из самой программы: делать из базы такие случайные выборки, чтобы объекты влезали в 500 Мб. Правда, я не знаю, сколько памяти будет кушать сама база, когда пойдут выборки из нескольких сот миллионов. Смысл этого финта ушами в том, чтобы обойти ограничение по памяти и смоделировать миллионы лет эволюции